# How to add theme support to Android Launcher

Tags: android

Im currently building a custom exclusive launcher for the Android HTC Sense 6 firmware. All is going well except Im stumped on how to incorperate the concept of adding theme support to my launcher to allow the use of themes like ADW, Go, Nova, ect...
I found this open source which looks like something that came from a launcher concept from CM7 and Ive been playing with it for support in Android 4.2.2 but with a theme installed in my device, it looks like it doesnt pickup. Any help would be appeciated as Im not exactly the best code junky around.
https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_launcher/source/68121bf7a9989d4319d3caf3ef78afef80df4ad8:src/com/android/launcher/ThemeSelector.java

[image]